# Azure Web App upload Docker-Compose file through C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-sdk-.net

I'm looking for C# SDK example to upload a Docker-Compose file while creating Azure Web App. My sole requirement is to upload a multi-container-based web app through C# SDK programmatically. I've tried exploring the Azure-Samples repository in GitHub but couldn't find any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using Microsoft.Azure.Management.* SDK and there is a new Azure.ResourceManager.*

Here is the code to deploy a multi-container apps to app service

```
public void NewMultiContainerApps(string resourceGroupName)
{
    string composeFilePath="your compose file path";
    string appServicePlanName="app service plan name";
    string appServiceName="app service name";
    var resourceGroup = this.client.GetDefaultSubscription().GetResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).Value;
    var appServicePlanData = new AppServicePlanData("centralus");
    appServicePlanData.Sku = new Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models.SkuDescription();
    appServicePlanData.Sku.Name = "S1";
    appServicePlanData.Sku.Tier = "Standard";
    appServicePlanData.Sku.Size = "S1";
    appServicePlanData.Sku.Family = "S";
    appServicePlanData.Sku.Capacity = 1;
    appServicePlanData.Kind = "linux";            
    appServicePlanData.MaximumElasticWorkerCount = 1;
    appServicePlanData.Reserved = true;
    var appServicePlan = resourceGroup.GetAppServicePlans().CreateOrUpdate(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, appServicePlanName, appServicePlanData);

    var websiteData = new WebSiteData("centralus");    
    websiteData.ServerFarmId = appServicePlan.Value.Id;
    var composeFile = File.ReadAllText(composeFilePath);
    var base64ComposeFile = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(composeFile));
    websiteData.SiteConfig = new Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models.SiteConfigProperties();
    websiteData.SiteConfig.LinuxFxVersion = $"COMPOSE|{base64ComposeFile}";
    websiteData.SiteConfig.NetFrameworkVersion = "v4.6";
    websiteData.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn = true;
    websiteData.SiteConfig.LocalMySqlEnabled = false;
    websiteData.SiteConfig.Http20Enabled = true;
    websiteData.SiteConfig.AppSettings = new List<Azure.ResourceManager.AppService.Models.NameValuePair>();
    websiteData.ScmSiteAlsoStopped = false;
    websiteData.HttpsOnly = false;
    websiteData.IsXenon = false;
    websiteData.HyperV = false;
    websiteData.Reserved = false;
    var website = resourceGroup.GetWebSites().CreateOrUpdate(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, appServiceName, websiteData);

}
```